# systemVerilog- how can I use $urandom/$random with range?

Tags: random, system-verilog

Is there  a way to use $urandom/$random with range?

I succeeded to do it with max range in the following way (in this case 11 is the max range):

```
 temp = (($urandom(9)%11));
```

But how can I do it for max and min, for example max=11, min =8.

Answer (score 1):

You need `$urandom_range`, eg:

```
temp = $urandom_range(maxVal,minVal);
```

`minVal` is optional; the minimum value will be zero if you leave it out.

Comment: I can't use $urandom_range because I want to be able to use seed.

Comment: @sara8d `$urandom_range` is seeded the same way as `$urandom`. How that is done is vendor-specific. How `$random` is seeded is defined in the Verilog standard, but if you use `$random`, you only get one random number generator so you get poor _random stability_.

Comment: that's the reason that each transaction will get different seed.

Comment: @sara8d Not necessarily. It depends how you've coded it. In System-verilog, if you use `$urandom`, `$urandom_range` or `randomize()`, each thread will have its own random number generator (RNG) and that RNG is seeded from the parent thread. So, the seed for each thread depends on the state of the RNG of the parent thread when the thread is spawned. So, when you randomize a transaction, the RNG uses the seed of the thread that executed `$urandom`,  `$urandom_range` or `randomize()` which generally is the thread being used by the code in the _sequencer_ (or whatever you want to call it).

Comment: @sara8d By coincidence, [my company](http://www.doulos.com) has just run [this webinar](http://www.doulos.com/content/events/random_stability.php) and is running it again later today. I think you might find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

Also note that arguments to $urandom_range are int unsigned, so -1 would be treated as a very positive number and if minVal is greater than maxVal, they are swapped automatically.

$urandom_range is very handy, but you could also look at std::randomize() and have an in-line constraint using an 'inside', for instance:

```
ok = std::randomize(a) with {a inside {0, [12:23], 42}; };
```

Take a look at https://www.edaplayground.com/x/3yEW

Comment: @jonesofcam- I can't use randomize(() because I use ModelSim which doesn't support it.